# Keyboard shortcut for cycling through changes in vscode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I know I can `Ctrl+Tab` between open editor files. Is there a way to cycle through the changed files using a keyboard shortcut, instead of clicking on the file names?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That does not seem to be supported yet (April 2017, up to vscode 1.11.1):

- nothing in [`src/vs/workbench/parts/git/browser/gitActions.ts`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/689d47663afc2e19b72464b14ed5d21a0e71eba7/src/vs/workbench/parts/git/browser/gitActions.ts) suggests you can cycle through Changes
- There is [no issues regarding that feature](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=git%20changes%20tab&type=Issues) (only the [ability to filter files in "Changes"](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24370))